# What does 声をかける mean?

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence in a book for kids.

> ライオンがずぶ濡れのヤギを見ました。ライオンはヤギに『うちに入って、雨やどりをしないか』と声をかけました。

There are many meanings on the internet but i can't quite understand its meaning.

Thank you all :)

Comment: Out of all the meanings you found, which one do you think it is?

Answer (score 4):

> 「声{こえ}をかける」

is quite different in meaning from

> 「話{はな}す」

in that you can 話す to/with someone for hours if you wanted, but you cannot 声をかける to someone for longer than a minute or two.

That is because the basic meaning of 「声をかける」 is "***to strike a conversation***", which means that it refers to the first couple of phrases or sentences uttered.

Thus, if you just said "Hi!" to another person, you  already 声をかけた to him/her.

Answer (score 1):

～に声をかける simply means *talk to* in a normal mild tone in that context.
It can also mean to mention an event to someone to stimulate their participation or just to invite them.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it simply means to call out to. The lion called out to the goat.

Comment: Would you mind expanding the answer to make it more useful for other people that may have the same question in the future?